# Class names and imports as variables in Python

Tags: python

I want a separate Python code where I can define default .py files that have to be created at the start of a project, depending on what models I want. So when I start a new project, I don't have to copy the code from a different project and adjust class names, etc. So for instance, I want to automatically create a model_1.py as:

```
class Model1(object):
   code
```

and a model_2.py as:

```
class Model2(object):
   code
```

I want these to be created from another file, where I define which models have to be created. So for instance:

```
models = ['Model1', 'Model2']
```

Is it possible to have the class name as a variable? So something like:

```
class models[0]()
```

Moreover, is something similar possible for the import part? So

```
from model_type_x.test import *
```

where model_type_x is a variable?

What other possibilities are there? Let Python create a text file and turn this into a .py file?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried already

Answer (score 0):

You need [this](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) module named cookiecutter. You can have templates for your project and have them configured with a prompt to create your project

Answer (score 0):

First of all, python file are simply text files. You just have to save them with a `.py` extension.

What you're trying to achieve is more or less out of the scope of python. Python by itself doesn't generate code. If you want to generate code, you can use templates in any language that you like. It doesn't really matter much since the code isn't going to get executed.

Class names and import names cannot be variables. These are syntax sugar allowing you to define types or import code.

If you want to import using a variable name, you can import modules as such:

```
__import__(module_name)
```

Where module_name is a variable so you can import modules at runtime with this if you can guess how they are called or going to be imported... Even though it's possible to do that, I do not recommend using this method as it's pretty ugly and pretty much useless to do that that way since we usually know beforehand what we're importing. You can always use the "*" but that's also not a particularly good idea because some things inside a module won't get exported and it's usually better to explicitly tell what you're importing.

```
class models[0]()
```

This is clearly not possible, the keyword class is used to define a type. What you can do on the other hand is this:

```
locals()[models[0]] = type(models[0], parent_tuple, attributes)
```

But accessing `locals()` to define a local variable using the `type` constructor to define a new type manually instead of using the `class` keyword that makes things much more easily to read... There's just no point to do otherwise.

The real question here is... What are you trying to achieve? Chances are that you're not looking for the right solution to a problem you don't have.